# Why 'AppModel' is not found when using model constants?

Tags: php, cakephp

This may be a silly question, but I have a weird behaviour with CakePHP 2.3.

In my model, I have defined some constants:

```
class ImageSpecification extends AppModel {
  public $name = 'ImageSpecification';

  const THUMBNAIL = 1;
  const NORMAL = 2;
  const HIDEF = 3;
  const EXTRA = 4;
  [...]
}
```

In `ImagesController`, I do a `App:uses('ImageSpecification', 'Model')` and I can load `ImageSpecification` data successfully, after using `$this->loadModel('ImageSpecification')`.  But, as soon I'm using a constant, (ie:  `ImageSpecification::THUMBNAIL`), it fails and I have the error:

> Fatal error: Class 'AppModel' not found in ../app/Model/ImageSpecification.php on line 2

`AppModel.php` is in `/app/Model` directory.  Without changing any code, other models just work fine, and if I'm using the constant value directly instead of using constant, all is fine too for `ImageSpecification` / `ImagesController`.  So, what's the problem here?  Language or syntax error in PHP?

Comment: So where exactly do you access the constants? After calling `Controller::loadModel()`? Or are you talking about two different scenarios? ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Answer (score 0):

That is because your models are not correctly set up.
You are missing a few vital App::uses() calls.
In your case probably in your model class at the top:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class ImageSpecification extends AppModel {...}
```

You need to ALWAYS include all used classes in a file at the top.
Not doing so will get you in trouble - as you just experienced yourself.

Same goes for your controller, if you want to access a models constant without having loaded it yet.
Then you need this at the top of your controller, of course:

```
App:uses('ImageSpecification', 'Model')
```

And then you will be able to access the constants without any issue (you dont have to load or initialize the class for it).

Answer (score -1):

A) You could just use the object instance instead, rather than the class

B) You could use `App::import` instead to load the class rather than an instance of it.